# Connect to a remote mysql server on AWS with FQDN from mysql client on windows AWS server with FQDN

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

Cannot connect to remote mysql server with FQDN from a mysql client on windows server. Both these servers are in AWS. I can connect with IP and wildcard '%'. How to make it work with fully qualified domain name (FQDN).

Mysql client can connect to remote mysql server in below 2 ways:

**With IP** 
Grant access to IP with below commands:

```
create user '<USER>'@'<Windows IP>' identified by '<PWD>';
grant all PRIVILEGES on <DBNAME>.* to '<USER>'@'<Windows IP>' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

**With wildcard**
Grant access with wildcard `'<USER>'@'%'` which means user from any host can access it, which may have security concerns.

**Since the IP changes, we need to make it work with FQDN**. When granting access with FQDN, getting below error.
Error exc: ('HY000', "[HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver]Host '' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server (1130) (SQLDriverConnect);

Comment: which IP address are you using internal or external ? When we create an EC2 instance, we get an external IP address which is similar to: ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XX.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com.... For this, you need to provide the 'internal ip address" of the EC2 instance

Comment: We need to make it work with fully qualified domain name and not the ip address as it is dynamic.

Comment: can you post your EC2 Security group & DB Security group screenshot to verify all inbound rules.